# How do I use Parameters and ReturnType with generics?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a helper function for a method of a property that's declared through a generic type parameter. Unfortunately, I can only get the code to compile when I use a concrete type and not the generic type parameter. Minimal example below.

```js
// Adapted from https://github.com/abalabahaha/eris, licence MIT
declare class Message<T extends Textable = Textable> {
    channel: T;
}
interface Textable {
    createMessage(content: string, file?: string | string[]): Promise<Message>;
}

function test<T extends Textable>(...args: Parameters<T["createMessage"]>) {
    void args;
}

// This compiles when the generic isn't used and Textable is specified explicitly
export default async function reply<T extends Textable>(
    msg: Message<T>,
    ...args: Parameters<Textable["createMessage"]>
): ReturnType<Textable["createMessage"]> {
    test(...args);
    return await msg.channel.createMessage(...args);
}

// This does not compile when the generic is actually used
export default async function reply<T extends Textable>(
    msg: Message<T>,
    ...args: Parameters<T["createMessage"]>
): ReturnType<T["createMessage"]> { // The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<Message<Textable>>'?
    test(...args); // still compiles
    msg.channel.createMessage(args[0], args[1]); // still compiles
    return await msg.channel.createMessage(...args); // Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0 or more. An argument for 'content' was not provided.
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Read the error. `async` functions return `Promise`s.

Comment: Then why does the first example work and not the second? I've used cases like the first example before; if the ReturnType of the original function is indeed a Promise, then it works out since ReturnType<U> = Promise<V>

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread One of your function signatures . I think I see the issue and I'm going to investigate it further

Comment: I think it doesnt work with the generic because there is a possibility for you to override the `createMessage` function in `Message` which will makes the arguments to differ. Everytime there is a possibility for a data to be modified, typescript takes the possibility in count and raise errors accordingly.